# vertically align text and buttons

Tags: html, css

I wanted to center both the buttons and the text vertically, but the text as seen in the photo

[image]

is lower than the rest. If I remove the buttons, the text goes to center as it should, but if I leave the buttons, the text goes back down (How i wish it was).

[image]

```css
.song {
  /*DivButtonTitle*/
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  color: #551A8B;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'flat';
  height: 80px;
  border-top: solid 1px #551A8B;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #551A8B;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="song">
  <button class="start" id="1" name="Gentleman-GUE/01._T_Apposto.mp3" onclick="togglePlay(this.id, this.name)"></button>
  <button class="restart" onclick="toggleRestart()"></button>
  <a>T'Apposto</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flexbox to the rescue.

Just add:

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
```

I.E:

```css
.song {
  /*DivButtonTitle*/
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  color: #551A8B;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'flat';
  height: 80px;
  border-top: solid 1px #551A8B;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #551A8B;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="song">
  <button class="start" id="1" name="Gentleman-GUE/01._T_Apposto.mp3" onclick="togglePlay(this.id, this.name)">start</button>
  <button class="restart" onclick="toggleRestart()">restart</button>
  <a>T'Apposto</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked greatly, where can I find some help/reference about flexbox?I never heard of that.

Comment: [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a great tutorial, note that it's not fully supported on IE < 11

Answer (score 0):

Try to  take your  text in `<span id ='foo'>  Your text here </span>`

And then you can edit it  as you want to  in your CSS.

A nice guide that I can suggest for centering the items with CSS  ;

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

One way that would work is to use flexbox:

```css
.song {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  color: #551A8B;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'flat';
  
  height: 80px;
  border-top: solid 1px #551A8B;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #551A8B;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.song button {
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="song">
  <button class="start"></button>
  <button class="restart"></button>
  <a>T'Apposto</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This also works well, but what does "justify-content: flex-start;" mean?

Comment: Oh it is kinda obsolete. It tells where it is aligned horizontally. Bit the inital value is flex-start anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out for your CSS:

```
.song{/*DivButtonTitle*/
margin-bottom:3px;
color:#551A8B;
font-size:35px;
font-family:'flat';
height:80px;
border-top:solid 1px #551A8B;
border-bottom:solid 1px #551A8B;
width:100%;
line-height: 80px;
padding:0px;
}
```

and add the following to a class associated with your buttons:

```
.buttonClass{
vertical-align:middle;
}
```